# Maximum range of a projectile (launched from an elevation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

> If a projectile is launched at a speed $u$ from a height $H$ above the horizontal axis, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, and air resistance is ignored, its trajectory is
> $$y=H+x \tan θ-x^2\frac g{2u^2}\left(1+\tan ^2\theta\right),$$
> and its maximum range is
> $$R_{\max }=\frac ug\sqrt{u^2+2gH}.$$

I would like to derive the above $R_{\max},$ and here's what I've done:

1. substitute $(x,y)=(R,0)$ into the trajectory equation;
2. differentiate the result with respect to $\theta;$
3. substitute $\left(R,\frac {\mathrm dR}{\mathrm
       d\theta}\right)=\left(R_{\max},0\right).$

However, this eliminates $H$ and fails to lead to the desired expression for $R_{\max }.$ How to actually derive the above $R_{\max }?$

P.S. This is the context; in the above, I've replaced all occurrences of $L$ below with $\frac{u^2}g$.

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127300/11127

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you described, we substitute $y=0$ and $x=R$ into the trajectory equation:
$$0=H+R\tan{\theta}-R^2\frac{g}{2u^2}\sec^2\theta.\tag{1}$$
Then, differentiating with respect to $\theta$ and setting $\frac{dR}{d\theta}=0$:

$$0=R_{max}\sec^2\theta-R_{max}^2\frac{g}{2u^2}2\sec^2\theta\tan\theta,$$
which simplifies to
$$R_{max}=\frac{u^2}{g}\cot\theta.\tag{2}$$
Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ will yield the desired expressions for $\theta$ and $R_{max}$.

Comment: Beautiful! THANK YOU! ps. I've cleaned up this page to make it more general and useful.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting concepts from the question and solutions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660468/interesting-relationship-between-minimum-launch-and-terminal-velocities-of-a-pro/2687554#2687554), we have

$$R_\text{max}=\frac {uw}g=\color{red}{\frac ug\sqrt{u^2+2gH}}$$
and
$$\tan\theta^*=\frac {\ell-H}{\sqrt{\ell^2-H^2}}
=\frac {\frac {u^2}g}{\frac ug \sqrt{u^2+2gH}}=\color{red}{\frac u{\sqrt{u^2+2gH}}}$$
where $\ell$ is the linear distance between the launch and end points of the projectile.

*Addendum:*

Here $\tan\theta^*$ was derived using $\theta^*=\frac \pi 4+\frac\alpha 2$, which leads to 
$$\tan\theta^*=\frac {1+\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=\frac {\ell (1+\sin\alpha)}{\ell\cos\alpha}=\frac{\ell -H}{R_{\text{max}}}$$
as $\alpha$ is negative in this case.

Comment: where did you get that second tan equation from?

Comment: @Achilles'Advisor - see explanation in Addendum.