# Maximum range of a projectile (launched from the cave)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

[image]

*A cannon located under a cave forms an alpha angle with the horizontal launching a series of projectiles. The cannon is at point A, at a distance L from the base of the cave (point B). If the initial velocity of each projectile is v0, determine the maximum horizontal range one of these projectiles can have.*

PS.: 45 degree angle releases hit the cave

Hello,

I struggled to find the correct algebrated manipulation to find this answer.
Besides all those hints: [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571/what-is-the-optimum-angle-of-projection-when-throwing-a-stone-off-a-cliff) and [HERE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/maximum-range-of-a-projectile-launched-from-an-elevation/23187#23187).

I cant progressing the expression about he related only $L_{max}$ and $\alpha$.

my height the ball is

$$h = \frac{v_0^2}{g}\left(1-\frac{1}{2\cdot \sin^2\theta}\right)$$

horizontal distante between position l to cliff.
$$\tan\alpha = \frac{h}{x+l}$$

my sketches:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scj89.jpg)

Comment: An English translation would be nice.

Comment: I put a simple translate about the problem.

Comment: I struggle to see why you have applied verbatim an equation for h "the height of the cliff" when in your problem there is no cliff. 
The way to solve this is use basic equations of motion, determining time from the vertical component of the journey, and then using that time to determine the horizontal component, the distance travelled.

Comment: Is it possible that $\sin^2(\cdot)$ is in fact $\sin(2\cdot)$ in the solution?

Comment: @JMLCarter sorry for my bad word description. But I wish you got the point.

Comment: @mechanodroid I really don't know. This is a question posted in the Facebook group.