# Is it possible to guess this solution just by looking at the system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> Show that, if a projectile is shot from a height $h$ with speed $v_0$, the maximum range is obtained for launch angle $\theta=\arctan\left(\dfrac{v_0}{\sqrt{2gh+v_0^2}}\right)$

For the problem shown above, I noticed how the numerator is the initial speed and the denominator is the final speed, and so I wonder if there's a way to solve this problem through some sort of physical insight and simple geometry maybe? I tried thinking for quite a while but I couldn't find an answer as to why the maximum range angle is the arctan of the ratio of the start and end speeds.

Comment: To clarify, is this saying that you need to launch at this angle to get the maximum range. i.e. the farthest horizontal distance before hitting the ground?

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes

Comment: Are you familiar with the *h* =0 limit of the formula, and do you have an inspection argument for it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't know what you mean by an inspection argument but yes, I did notice that when h = 0 , the maximum range angle comes out to be 45 degrees as expected, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Expected by a just-so explicit maximization solution?

Comment: One of the answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/maximum-range-of-a-projectile-launched-from-an-elevation) summarizes the geometrical construction best.

Comment: Note that the denominator is only the final speed I'm certain situations. Not in general.

Comment: @AaronStevens What are the cases when the denominator isn't the final speed? I can't think of any right now

Comment: Ah nevermind, I made an error